# Accessing first and second values of a pair in a set

Tags: stl, set

```
 #include <bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;

#define fast ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
#define LL long long int
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair
#define PII pair<int,int>
#define PLL pair<LL,LL>
#define PIS pair< int,string>


#define test int t;cin>>t;while(t--)
#define ff first // error: 'std::set<std::pair<long long int, long long int> >::iterator' has no member named 'first'
#define ss second // error: 'std::set<std::pair<long long int, long long int> >::iterator' has no member named 'second'
#define INF 1000000000
#define input(a,n) for(i=1;i<=n;i++)cin>>a[i];
#define output(a,n) for(i=1;i<=n;i++)cout<<a[i]<<" ";
vector< vector<LL> > v(3002, vector<LL>(3002,-1));
set< pair<LL, LL> > se;
set< pair<LL, LL> >::iterator it;
int vis[3002]={0};
void exmin(LL a)
{
    LL x,des,val,min=INF;
    for(x=0;x<v[a].size();x++)
    {
        if(v[a][x]<min)
        {
            val=v[a][x];
            des=x;
            min=val;
        }
    }
    se.insert(mp(val,des));
}


int main() {

  fast
  LL n,m,x,i,j,k,wt=0,s;
  cin>>n>>m;
  vector<int> ve;
  for(x=1;x<=n;x++)
     ve.pb(x);
  for(x=0;x<m;x++)
  {
    cin>>i>>j>>k;
    if(v[i][j]!=-1)
    {
        if(v[i][j]>k)
        {
            v[i][j]=k;
            v[j][i]=k;
          }
      }
      else
      {
        v[i][j]=k;
        v[j][i]=k;
      }

  }
  cin>>s;
  ve.erase(ve.begin()+s-1);
  while(ve.size()!=0)
  {
    for(x=0;x<v[s].size();x++)
    {
        if(v[s][x]!=-1 && vis[x]!=1)
        {
            exmin(x);
          }
    }
/*  for(x=0;x<p.size();x++)
    {

    }*/

    it=se.begin();
    wt=wt+*(it).ff;
    s=*(it).ss;
    vis[*(it).ss]=1;
    ve.erase(ve.begin()+*(it).ss-1);

    se.erase(it);
  }

return 0;
}
```

Still facing errors.
I am trying to implement **Prim's algorithm**.
Was not able to include the line numbers, hence attached the errors along with the lines itself.
Sorry , but could not help including the "abhorrent part" because the error is in that part.

Edit:
Found my mistake , it was a syntactical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have a global set `s`

```
set< pair<LL, LL> > s;
```

You have also defined a local variable `s` of type long long:

```
LL n,m,x,i,j,k,wt=0,s;
```

which hides the global `s`. Obviously a `long long` has neither `begin` nor `erase` member functions since it is a primitive type. Hence the errors:

```
 it=s.begin();    //error: request for member 'begin' in 's', which is of non-class type 'long long int'

 s.erase(it);  //error: request for member 'erase' in 's', which is of non-class type 'long long int'
```

To refer to the global `s`, use `::s`, i.e.

```
::s.erase(it);
```

And lastly I want to point out that this "contestese" coding style you're using is abhorrent. Feel free to use it during contests as much as you like, but please edit it away when you post questions on SO.

Comment: Thanks!! how could I have missed that, but still facing some errors , have updated my code

Answer (score 0):

Found the error in my code.

```
wt=wt+*(it).ff;
```

instead of *(it) it should have been (*it)

Comment: Just FYI, we have a special `operator ->` to use in this case. I.e. `it->ff` instead of `(*it).ff`